# Parallel capacitor affecting voltage divider circuit

Tags: voltage-divider

Ran into a bit of a strange issue with a voltage divider. I take the voltage of a single cell li-ion and divide it down to a 0 - 3V range so it can be read by an ESP32, I then multiply this voltage by a fixed constant to know what the battery voltage is.

This same circuit has been built on 50+ PCB's but I'm only seeing the issue on 2 specific boards. There is a parallel capacitor for some filtering, but on these 2 specific boards, with this capacitor fitted the voltage reported by the ESP32 is incorrect. Not by a huge amount, in the region of ~200mV.

If I remove the capacitor the voltage is reported correctly.

What I'm struggling to understand is how a parallel capacitor which should in theory be open circuit at DC, is affecting the voltage divider circuit.

Is anyone able to shed any light on why this is happening?

EDIT: Capacitor used is an 0402 X5R 10uF 6.3V MLCC - Kemet C0402C106M9PACTU [(Datasheet)](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/447/KEM_C1006_X5R_SMD-3316465.pdf) [(Spec sheet)](https://search.kemet.com/component-documentation/download/specsheet/C0402C106M9PACTU)

[image]

Comment: What's the leakage current of the capacitor? What type is it?

Comment: Did you check the capacitor polarity for these 2 specific boards?

Comment: Added capacitor type in edit, ceramic cap so no polarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible reasons-

1. the capacitors could be damaged and leaky.
2. the ESP32 ADC input (like most unbuffered SAR converters, though this is not a particularly impressive one) draws a certain amount of current every time you make a measurement. There's a small capacitor  that needs to be charged through a resistor (14pF and 1kΩ if memory serves). You have a relatively high impedance divider (16kΩ+), so depending on how you are using the ADC (measuring rate etc.) you can have effects like this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like quite a big capacitor for this use case. Maybe the internal resistance of the capacitor influences the voltage divider. Is the voltage too low or too high?

Comment: Changing the capacitor to a 1uF rather than 10uF has resolved the issue. It still doesn't answer the why the 10uF value causes the drop but at least is a solution

Comment: @Mukira It was already stated by both winny and Spehro: It is leaky. That means it's passing current and loading down your divider. This can be measured.